# MAC spoofing under a OPN Access point HTTP does not work

Tags: wifi, http, mac-spoofing

I want to do a demo on the wifi security. So, I have one Wifi router and two client.

I configured my router without security (OPN) and with a MAC filter.

One of the two client is connected to the router and sends infinite ping on the router.

So, with the other client, I capture the legetimate MAC adress with airodump and I change my MAC adress with macchanger.

After this, I am well connected on the router and I can ping google.com without problems.

But when I try to access a web page (http), It does not work.

I do not understand why? If I have a conflict with the MAC adress, normally I can not ping with both.

Regards,

sushi

Comment: Have you tried to access the Internet from client 1 before applying the attack? maybe it's irrelative problem.

Comment: Also, be sure that your MAC has changed by accessing http and monitoring it using Wireshark.

Comment: During the demo time, it worked for all people without me lol. Anyway, maybe my router is just too old or broke. thx for your answer.